# Returning a list and getting to the items in Hedgehog state machine

Tags: haskell, haskell-hedgehog

I have a model for a state machine that is

```
newtype State (v :: * -> *) = State (M.Map (Var UUID v) DataPerItem)
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I then have a `Command gen exec [Update update]` with `exec` returning a list of `UUID`, i.e. it has type

```
exec :: action -> m [UUID]
```

which in turns mean that `update` needs a type like this

```
update :: State v -> action -> Var [UUID] v -> State V
```

AFAICS I need to, in order to actually update my model, turn that `Var [UUID] v` into `[Var UUID v]`. I've been staring at the functions in Hedgehog for a while now but nothing jumps out... or am I, once again, thinking about it all wrong? :)

Comment: What is ``Var`` here?

Comment: `Var` is documented [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog-1.0.1/docs/Hedgehog.html#t:Var).

Comment: Ouch, seems to be a known, and unfixed, issue: https://github.com/hedgehogqa/haskell-hedgehog/issues/113

Answer (score 1):

This can't work, but there's a good reason why.

Think of state machine testing as automatic writing a test programs, where each `Var a Symbolic` as a binding in the program.

So imagine I was testing a little buffer, with operations `create :: Size -> Buf`, `put :: Buf -> Int -> IO ()` and `get :: Buf -> IO Int`.

I could hand roll a unit test.

```
test :: TestT IO ()
test = do
  buf <- create 3
  put buf 5
  put buf 10
  put buf 20
  retrieved <- get buf
  retrieved === Just 5
```

with appropriate commands, hedgehog could also generate this exact test as

```
test :: TestT IO ()
test = do
  Var 1 = create 3
  Var 2 = put (Var 1) 5
  Var 3 = put (Var 1) 10
  Var 4 = put (Var 1) 20
  Var 5 = get (Var 1)
  Var 5 === Just 5
```

So each execution is given a variable name.

When you way you want something like this:

```
splitNames :: Var [UUID] v -> [Var UUID v]
```

What you're asking for is essentially each return from the execution list to be given its own variable name. The rest of the program could then use those variable names. The best way I can think to show this is:

```
test :: TestT IO ()
test = do
  Var 1 = returnSomeNumberOfItems
  Var 2 = Var 1 ! 0
  Var 3 = Var 1 ! 1
```

Now the issue here is that we just don't know how long the list returned by `returnSomeNumberOfItems` is; we haven't run it yet; there's no way to do this safely.

Comment: The `action` _does_ specify exactly how many items will be in the list, so that's not a problem in this case. In any case, I managed to work around this by switching to `quickcheck-state-machine`.